# Will I upgrade to Ubuntu if I use dist-upgrade in Xubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, upgrade, update-manager, xubuntu

Will `update-manager -d` in Xubuntu 11.04 install standard Ubuntu (with Unity and all) or will it just upgrade to Xubuntu 11.10? If anyone did so, did you have experience concerning stability or complete breakdown after an upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the upgrade will just install Xubuntu 11.10.